# Why is Dell XPS 15 9500 wifi card not recognized on Ubuntu 21.04 Hirsute?

Tags: drivers, wireless, dell, atheros, 21.04

After reading many contributions about the support of the Killer wifi card of the Dell XPS 15 9500 with the 5.10/5.11 kernels, I decided to install Ubuntu 21.04 Hirsute which provides the 5.11 kernel by default.

Everything on the laptop is working fine, great!
But not the wifi card :-(

- lspci shows the wifi card
- lsmod shows the various ath11k modules loaded
- ifconfig or ip show only the lo interface

What is missing on this installation to recognize the wifi card?

Comment: Let's have a look at the message log for clues. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep ath` I suspect that you lack the needed firmware.

Answer (score 0):

New XPS 15 with fresh 21.04 install two weeks ago.

I'm having issues, twice in the past 2 weeks, on my new XPS 15 9500 and 21.04 with wifi working fine initially then not available.  lspci shows the card.

After trying numerous troubleshooting options found online in desperation I usb boot back to 20.10.  wifi isn't available there either.

Reboot to installed 21.04 and mysteriously wifi is back on.

I have no idea if booting into trial 20.10 fixed it or if it is incidental???